# Wave Particle Duality - Weight?

Tags: waves, wave-particle-duality, duality

Regards the issue of wave particle duality and the double slit experiment.

If the experiment was run with the ’screen’ and detector as a 'box', with electrons being sent into the box from an external source and this box was placed on a set of scales and measurements taken before and after the experiment.

If the electron is a particle, then over time would many of the ‘particles' remain within the box and as they have mass would they add to the weight of the box?

If the electron is a wave then would the wave eventually dissipate and the weight of the box remain unchanged?

Comment: The electron is neither a wave nor a particle.

Comment: The electron isn't a wave, and it isn't a particle. The electron is a quantum-mechanical object, with some wave-like and some particle-like properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you distribute the boxes at various positions and placed them on scales, then over time boxes would one by one get heavier.

And eventually you would notice that some boxes got much more heavy than others. There would be regions where the boxes got lots heaver and region where the boxes only got a little bit heavier and regions in between where the boxes got an in between amount heavier.

The function of how much heavier the box got would look wavey.

Comment: Thumbs up with the caveat that at the scale on which one can actually perform electron diffraction experiments a few electrons are actually enough to charge a suitable size "box" to such a high potential that its electrostatic field with significantly modify the experiment and potentially shut down the flow of further electrons completely.

Comment: @CuriousOne I agree, but to be convincing that anything unusual is happening you should send the electrons in slowly so they arrive one at a time and then the boxes can first aquire the electron, then a positive ion. And so if the electrons come slowly enough eventually the increase in mass won't just be a per-electron amount but a per-electron and and average per-positive-ion amount.

Comment: Ah... now we are talking about the difference between theory and practice... One wonders, though, if there has been a successful measurement of an electron mass on anything larger than a molecule.

Comment: @CuriousOne I said eventually, so you can run the experiment for a long time, and as long as there isn't a systematic bias to lose or gain mass then the scales should depress in a manner proportional to the wave pattern predicted by theory. When I said much more I meant the more was much more, not that the boxes would actually double their weight or anything.